# Is it possible to modify the article class file?

Tags: article, documentclass-writing

I would like to write a new class file, preferably from scratch (if that is not way too time consuming). I do not want it to take too long to compile an empty document. The one I have written now uses `LoadClass` and I think it takes a bit too long to compile my custom cls-file and it is not yet finished.

The base shoule be `article`. Is it possible to edit the file (and save with a different name)? In particular I would like to define page margins with `geometry`, change all default fonts with `fontspec` and also redefine the font size in the `size1\@ptsize.clo` and also `\baslineskip` and probably many more parameters.

Can I change the `article.cls` in that way or do I have to write a new class and use `LoadClass`?

Comment: Yes, you can rename a copy of `article.cls` and edit it accordingly.  You will have to make sure that your TeX installation can find it in the file structure, if it is located anywhere other than the current directory.

Comment: `\LoadClass` is optional. You can write a new document class without loading an existing one.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer! It works for now without errors!

Comment: To write a new class file from scratch,  rename a copy of `minimal.cls` and modify as you need. However, I am very sceptic about obtain significant reductions in compilation times doing that. For sure, the minimal gain will not compensate the lost of hours invested in make and test a new class.

Comment: Yes, that might be the case! I found that making it completly from scratch would be to extensive so I am using the ```article.cls``` as the base and modifying stuff instead. I would like it to be as "clean" as possible (I am on a tight schedule) without unnecessary definitions.